# Как упростить этот код javascript

Tags: javascript

в жс я нолик ) Передо мной встала написать код, я сделал, оно работает, но хотелось бы узнать как можно упростить эту громадину

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                const form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
                const form2 = document.getElementById('form2');
                const form3 = document.getElementById('form3');
                const form4 = document.getElementById('form4');

                const btnS1 = document.getElementById('btnS1');
                const btnS2 = document.getElementById('btnS2');
                const btnS3 = document.getElementById('btnS3');
                const btnS4 = document.getElementById('btnS4');

                btnS1.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    form1.classList.add('active');
                    form2.classList.remove('active');
                    form3.classList.remove('active');
                    form4.classList.remove('active');
                });
                btnS2.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    form2.classList.add('active');
                    form1.classList.remove('active');
                    form3.classList.remove('active');
                    form4.classList.remove('active');
                });
                btnS3.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    form3.classList.add('active');
                    form1.classList.remove('active');
                    form2.classList.remove('active');
                    form4.classList.remove('active');
                });
                btnS4.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    form4.classList.add('active');
                    form1.classList.remove('active');
                    form2.classList.remove('active');
                    form3.classList.remove('active');
                });
            });
```

Comment: если какой-то из вариантов вам помог, то, пожалуйста,  отметьте его галочкой слева от наиболее полезного сообщения. Также если ответ помог Вам, то не лишним будет и проголосовать за него (нажать на стрелочку вверх слева от вопроса) ... Это касается всех ваших вопросов... Иначе пользователи в дальнейшем просто перестанут отвечать на ваши вопросы и будут вас игнорировать. см: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял как должна выглядеть разметка, то проще всего было использовать механику **табов** (вкладок).

Написал механику под неё, теперь можно кнопок и "форм" создавать хоть *миллион*

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let btns = document.querySelector('.btns'),
      forms = document.querySelector('.forms');

  btns.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let target = e.target.closest('.btn');
    if(target) {
      let id = target.getAttribute('data-form');
      
      if(!target.classList.contains('active')) {
        let old = btns.querySelector('.btn.active');
        if(old) old.classList.remove('active');
        target.classList.add('active');
        
        let form = forms.querySelector('#'+id);
        if(form) {
          old = forms.querySelector('.form.active');
          if(old) old.classList.remove('active');
          form.classList.add('active');
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.btns .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btns .btn:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.btns .btn.active {
  color: green;
}

.forms .form {
  display: none;
}

.forms .form.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns">
  <div class="btn" data-form="form-1">form 1</div>
  <div class="btn" data-form="form-2">form 2</div>
  <div class="btn" data-form="form-3">form 3</div>
  <div class="btn" data-form="form-4">form 4</div>
</div>

<div class="forms">
  <div id="form-1" class="form">form 1</div>
  <div id="form-2" class="form">form 2</div>
  <div id="form-3" class="form">form 3</div>
  <div id="form-4" class="form">form 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно немного проще написать: https://jsfiddle.net/se46cagz/

Comment: @Deonis, так добавьте своё решение ответом.

Comment: @Deonis, да и у меня решение без циклов. Да и можно ещё упростить, вообще без JS, оставить это на HTML+CSS..

Comment: @Deonis и самый важный + в том что в этом ответе использоватся делегирование событий, что позволят на ходу добавлять формы и кнопки. И не завязываться на вёрстке. В моём ответе тоже нет делегирования, но зато нет прогулки по массиву на каждый клик

Comment: @De.Minov Можно глянуть, кто всем подряд -1 поставил или это анонимно полностью?)

Comment: @EzioMercer, тоже интересно, но увы, скорее всего известно только разрабам.

Answer (score 0):

Оставлю этот вариант, на случай, если вам не подойдет делегирование событий как в ответе `De.Minov` (т.е. кнопки и формы не находятся в одном большом блоке):

```js
const btnToFormsMap = new Map([
  ['btnS1', 'form1'],
  ['btnS2', 'form2'],
  ['btnS3', 'form3'],
  ['btnS4', 'form4'],
].map(item => [
  document.getElementById(item[0]),
  document.getElementById(item[1])
]));

let activedForm = null;

document.querySelectorAll('[id^=btnS]').forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const activeForm = btnToFormsMap.get(e.target);

  if (activedForm !== null) activedForm.classList.remove('active');

  activeForm.classList.add('active');
  activedForm = activeForm;
}));
```

```css
[id^=btnS] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

[id^=form].active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="btnS1">btnS 1</div>
<div id="btnS2">btnS 2</div>
<div id="btnS3">btnS 3</div>
<div id="btnS4">btnS 4</div>

<br/>

<div id="form1">form 1</div>
<div id="form2">form 2</div>
<div id="form3">form 3</div>
<div id="form4">form 4</div>
```

На самом деле можно и тут воспользоваться делегированием, навесив слушатель на весь документ, но подумал, что у вас скорее всего всё статично

Плюсы:

- Для поиска уже активного элемента и будущего активного элемента не надо ничего искать ни в DOM-е ни в массиве
- Очень легко построить нужные связи между кнопками и формами

Минусы:

- Это это не будет работать, если формы и кнопки у вас добавляются динамически, тогда вам необходим ответ `De.Minov`

Минус это или плюс, каждый решает для себя, но потребляет больший объём памяти для ускорения алгоритма

Answer (score -1):

Можно всем кнопкам задать 1 класс, вместо того чтобы каждый раз обращаться по id кнопки. И по атрибуту `data-target` у кнопки менять активный класс формы.

```js
const callToActionBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

callToActionBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    callToActionBtns.forEach(b => {
      form = document.querySelector(b.getAttribute('data-target'));
      form.classList.remove('active');
    });
    
    form = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute('data-target'));
    form.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.forms {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="form1" class="forms active">1</div>
  <div id="form2" class="forms">2</div>
  <div id="form3" class="forms">3</div>
  
  <button data-target="#form1" class="btn">1</button>
  <button data-target="#form2" class="btn">2</button>
  <button data-target="#form3" class="btn">3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Для примера. Вот как это будет выглядеть в jQuery

```js
window.onload = () => {
    $("form").each(function () {
        var $thisForm = $(this);
        $thisForm.click(function () {
            $('form').removeClass("active");
            $thisForm.addClass("active");
        });
    });
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: green !important;
}

form {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form1" action="">Form 1</form>
<form class="form2" action="">Form 2</form>
<form class="form3" action="">Form 3</form>
<form class="form4" action="">Form 4</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```